Calculating probability when a (particular) bias is involved
This is my first post in Math community.  I am a programmer, but I did math/statistics/probability at advanced level at school many, many years ago.  I hope I am posing a suitable question in an acceptable manner.
The question is about the expected outcome of dealing a pack of cards to a number of hands with a "bias" built in to make one hand come out with "better" cards than the others and quantifying the expected result for the biased hand.
The card game is Bridge.  All you need to know is:

A 52 card pack is randomly shuffled to produce an order in which the cards will be dealt out.
Cards are dealt one at a time to each of 4 players in turn, repeated 13 times to produce 4 hands of 13 cards..
A hand is "high-card counted" as follows: each Jack/Queen/King/Ace (Ace is higher than King) gives 1/2/3/4 points respectively.

There are thus 40 points in the pack and the average for each player is 10 points.  My code does this a million times and, not surprisingly, shows the average very close to 10.0.
I now wish to "bias" the deal so that my hand is likely to receive more than this average.  The algorithm is: each time a card is dealt to my hand I look through all the remaining, as-yet-undealt cards to see if the card of the same suit but 1 rank higher is still available.  (For example, if I am about to be dealt the 10 of Hearts I look to see if the Jack of Hearts is still in the pack to be dealt later.  If I am dealt the Ace of Hearts there will be no card of the same suit but higher rank.)
If I find that card I swap the card I was about to be dealt for the higher card and deal that to myself instead.  (So if I were about to be dealt the 10 of Hearts but I find the Jack of Hearts is still available in the undealt pack I put the 10 of Hearts into the position the Jack is in [for later distribution to whoever according to its place] and give myself the Jack.)  If the next-higher card is not available (it has already been dealt to whoever) then I do not do any swap, I receive the lower card as-is.  I trust this is clear.
The question is: what is the expected average number of points my "biased" hand will receive?  Empirically I run code for this a million times and find the result is around 11.61 instead of 10.0.
I am interested in knowing whether one can produce a mathematical formula which predicts this 11.61 figure?  Or, from what little I know about the subject, is this a problem for "numerical analysis" or "empirically trying with an algorithm and seeing what comes out" as I have done?
